# Crash on scrolling a fragment up/down continuously

Tags: android, crash, scroll, fragment

I hope somebody has an idea since this issue is getting me out of mind.

In my application I have an Activity that includes a fragment used to insert a new contact into the address book having the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frag_contact_add_linearLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#dddddd"   
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"   
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >      
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/frag_contact_add_contact_scroll_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#dddddd"             
        android:orientation="vertical"
        > 
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/frag_contact_add_contact_info"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"        
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp" 
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"       
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"       
            android:background="@drawable/contacts_lv_phone_number_style"        
            > 
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp">          
                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/frag_contact_add_avatar" 
                    android:layout_width="120dp" 
                    android:layout_height="120dp" 
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
                    android:src="@drawable/icona_user_profilo">              
                </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout> 

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="120dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"          
                > 
                <EditText
                       android:id="@+id/frag_contact_add_name" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_style"
                    android:textStyle="bold" 
                    android:textColor="#000000" 
                    android:textSize="20dp">          
                </EditText>
                <EditText
                       android:id="@+id/frag_contact_add_cogname" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:background="@drawable/textview_style"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" 
                    android:textColor="#000000" 
                    android:textSize="20dp">          
                </EditText>
            </LinearLayout> 

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/frag_contact_add_contact_number"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_below="@id/frag_contact_add_contact_info"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"          
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"        
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"        
            > 
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/frag_contact_add_iv_add"
                    android:layout_width="32dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/bt_plus_selector"
                    android:src="@drawable/transparent_pixel"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside">
                </ImageView>                 
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/frag_contact_info_add_linearLayout_items" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/contacts_lv_phone_number_style"
                > 
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/frag_contact_add_contact_save"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    > 
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/frag_contact_add_button_save"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/contacts_bt_save_selector">    
    </ImageView>      
</LinearLayout>            
</RelativeLayout>
```

The LinearLayout named "frag_contact_info_add_linearLayout_items" is a layout used to dynamically insert/delete items (a view) having a phone number details. Each view is inserted by inflating the view into the LinearLayout.

The single item named "view_contact_phone_element" has the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    > 
    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/contact_phone_phoneNumberTypeSpinner"
        android:layout_width="110dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:popupBackground="@drawable/contacts_spinner_phonenumbertype_style" 
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_background_selector"
        >
    </Spinner>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contact_phone_imageView_delete"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bt_meno_selector"
        android:src="@drawable    ransparent_pixel"
        android:scaleType="centerInside">
    </ImageView>     
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/contact_phone_textView_number"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"            
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/contact_phone_phoneNumberTypeSpinner"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/contact_phone_imageView_delete"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="0123456789" 
        android:textColor="#000000"                        
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        > 
    </EditText>        
</RelativeLayout>
```

When the onActivityCreated method is called the "frag_contact_info_add_linearLayout_items" layout is inflated with 4 "view_contact_phone_element" default views (having no phone numbers) using the loadPhoneNumbers() method:

```
private void loadPhoneNumbers() {
    View phoneNumberView = null;
    mPhoneNumbersLayout.removeAllViews();
    List<NgnPhoneNumber> sPhoneNumberItems = mNewContact.getPhoneNumbers();
    for (NgnPhoneNumber item : sPhoneNumberItems) {
        phoneNumberView = displayPhoneNumberItem(item);
    }
}

private View displayPhoneNumberItem(final NgnPhoneNumber item) {
    LayoutInflater lf = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
    View phoneItemView = lf.inflate(R.layout.view_contact_phone_element, null, false);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder();                
    mPhoneNumbersLayout.setTag(viewHolder);
    viewHolder.spinner=(Spinner)phoneItemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_phone_phoneNumberTypeSpinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> phoneNumberTypeAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.view_spinner, mPhoneNumberTypes);
    phoneNumberTypeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.drawable.spinner_text);
    viewHolder.spinner.setAdapter(phoneNumberTypeAdapter);
    viewHolder.spinner.setSelection(item.getPhoneType().ordinal());
    viewHolder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            item.setPhoneType(PhoneType.values()[position]);
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });    
    final TextView tvPhoneNumber = (TextView)phoneItemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_phone_textView_number);  
    tvPhoneNumber.setText(item.getNumber());    
    tvPhoneNumber.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View mView, MotionEvent mMotionEvent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onTouch(): motionEvent=" + mMotionEvent.toString());
            if(mMotionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                ((XTabFragContacts)mActivity).showPhoneNumberDialog(
                        mActivity.getClass().getCanonicalName(),
                        mNewContact, 
                        item,
                        mActivity,
                        mHandler);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }); 

    viewHolder.ivDelete = (ImageView)phoneItemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_phone_imageView_delete);
    viewHolder.ivDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                mNewContact.removePhoneNumber(item.getNumber());
                loadPhoneNumbers();
        }
    });

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mPhoneNumbersLayout.addView(phoneItemView, rlParams);
    return phoneItemView;
}
```

The problem is that scrolling this fragment up and down 3 or 4 times, causes my app to crash with the following log:

```
05-23 15:04:40.229: D/com.mydom.myapp.FragmentContactAdd(16209): onTouch(): motionEvent=MotionEvent{40623ea0 action=0 x=62.0 y=30.0 pressure=0.03137255 size=0.90999997}
05-23 15:04:40.239: D/com.mydom.myapp.FragmentContactAdd(16209): onTouch(): motionEvent=MotionEvent{40623ea0 action=2 x=61.0 y=29.0 pressure=0.03137255 size=0.95}
05-23 15:04:40.249: D/com.mydom.myapp.FragmentContactAdd(16209): onTouch(): motionEvent=MotionEvent{40623ea0 action=2 x=59.0 y=26.0 pressure=0.03137255 size=0.97999996}
05-23 15:04:40.259: D/com.mydom.myapp.FragmentContactAdd(16209): onTouch(): motionEvent=MotionEvent{40623ea0 action=2 x=57.0 y=19.0 pressure=0.03137255 size=0.98999995}
05-23 15:04:40.279: D/com.mydom.myapp.FragmentContactAdd(16209): onTouch(): motionEvent=MotionEvent{40623ea0 action=3 x=57.0 y=7.0 pressure=0.03137255 size=1.0}
05-23 15:04:41.649: W/dalvikvm(16209): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400ac560)
05-23 15:04:41.649: E/ACRA(16209): ACRA caught a StackOverflowError exception for com.mydom.myapp. Building report.
05-23 15:04:41.919: I/ACRA(16209): READ_LOGS granted! ACRA can include LogCat and DropBox data.
05-23 15:04:41.939: D/ACRA(16209): Retrieving logcat output...
05-23 15:04:42.099: D/ACRA(16209): Retrieving logcat output...
05-23 15:04:42.189: D/ACRA(16209): Writing crash report file 1369314282000.stacktrace.
05-23 15:04:42.229: D/ACRA(16209): About to send status bar notification from #handleException
05-23 15:04:42.229: D/ACRA(16209): Creating Notification for 1369314282000.stacktrace
05-23 15:04:42.259: D/ACRA(16209): Waiting for Toast + worker...
05-23 15:04:42.259: D/ACRA(16209): Wait for Toast + worker ended. Kill Application ? true
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209): com.mydom.myapp fatal error : null
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209): java.lang.StackOverflowError
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.View.addFocusables(View.java:3591)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:618)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.View.getFocusables(View.java:3559)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:109)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:93)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:476)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:478)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.View.focusSearch(View.java:3494)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.widget.TextView.onCreateInputConnection(TextView.java:4922)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:945)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.checkFocus(InputMethodManager.java:1129)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.isActive(InputMethodManager.java:542)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4368)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6880)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6986)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1703)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
05-23 15:04:42.289: E/ACRA(16209):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.jav
```

Note that I have this issue only on certain devices, like:
- Samsung GT-S5660 and GT-S6500 (running Android 2.3.6)
- Huawei U8186 (running Android 2.3.6)

While I have no issues on devices like Samsung GT-I9300, Samsung GT-I8190 and LG E400.

Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I solved by replacing the spinner in the "view_contact_phone_element" with a simple button. On button click I just open a Dialog showing the different lables that can be selected form the user.

I guess the spinner within a scrolling view can cause such kind of issues on certain devices.

Answer (score 1):

You got StackOverflowException, I think it happens because you are adding your views to LinearLayout, it tryes to invoke android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables() for each visible item, so you got StackOverflowException. LinearLayout can not handle so much possible visible elements, it is not good container for big amount of child views.

I think, you would better use [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) instead of adding your views to LinearLayout, also use [`ViewHolder`](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) pattern for better memory usage and speed performance of ListView.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I tried with a ListView in the past but I ran into the issue of having two nested scrollable components generating onTouch events (Spinners and ListView).

Comment: I had the same issue with a GridView...did you find a solution? Thx